# How can I customize headings in book-class?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting

I am writing my master thesis in the book-class in Latex and need some help to format the headings in the document. I have a Word-template from the University which have specific formats of the headings:

Heading 1 (Chapter): size 24 pt + left aligned + 75 pt spacing after
Heading 2 (Section): size 16 pt + left aligned + 30 pt before + 16 pt spacing after
Heading 3 (Subsection): size 12 pt + bold + left aligned + 24 pt spacing before + 12 pt spacing after
Heading 4 (Subsubsection): size 11 pt + italic + left aligned + 12 pt spacing before + 3 pt spacing after
Heading 5 (paragraph): size 11 pt + left aligned + 12 pt spacing before + 3 pt spacing after

I have been looking at the titlesec package and titleformat and found this:

```
\titleformat{<command>}[<shape>]{<format>}{<label>}{<sep>}{<before-code>}[<after-code>]
```

And it says that for format you can put \Large, \huge etc., but is there a way to say exactly what size the text should be in pt? And to specify the spacing in pt?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome, you can use `\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont`

Comment: Also \hspace{75pt}, etc.